# Weighting strength of synonymy in Apache solr

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp

I've been looking through the Apache solr java docs and it appears that it, by default still uses Lucene's weighting system for determining the strength of a match. It also allows for the explicit definition of synonyms, but as far as I can tell this is a strict binary definition and there doesn't exist a quantitative corollary of synonymy. Is this something that could be implemented within solr without a huge amount of rewriting code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a field with synonyms and give this a lower weight in the dismax. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660632/is-there-way-to-boost-original-term-more-while-using-solr-synonyms) for more info.